# File upload program using UDP protocol in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp, node-webkit

I wish to create a simple file upload program using UDP protocol in `node.js`. Is it possible to use it instead of TCP?  Any examples or suggestions?

Comment: why wouldnt you be able to? udp is just another way of sending data. it has no idea what that data might be. but why would use udp for file upload? that is extremely dangerous, since udp doesn't guarantee successfully sending a file (or notifying you that it failed to send.)

Comment: Doc: http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

Comment: @DTSCode I have a working oone in TCP, but as UDP is faster than TCP, so it can be used for lage file uploads.

Comment: @aymericbeaumet yes, I was watching on that one, and also made it to send messages from client to server, but I have to send a complete file  instead of the messages.

Comment: @Shikhar what makes you think tcp cant be used for larger file uploads? udp is faster yes, but the downside is the data you are uploading could end up bad\

Comment: If you do want to use UDP to send files, you will have to implement your own check algorithm to ensure the file integrity. Anyway, to send a file just read it and send its buffer?

Comment: Why do you want to use UDP instead of TCP? What real advantages do you expect? Just curious.

Comment: @aymericbeaumet I have been using TCP for larger files, but I thought if there was option to speed it up using UDP, it would have been better. Thanks.

Comment: @kol That's what I am asking. Is there any advantage of using UDP over TCP for file uploads?

Comment: It is in theory faster, but you will have to do a lot of work as said above. I'm not sure this a wise decision, but I do not know your needs.

Comment: Don't get sucked into premature optimization.

Comment: UDP is usually not faster than TCP, but it offers less latency at the cost of packet loss. This can be acceptable for real-time audio or video, but usually not for file transfer. TCP can be slower on high-latency links like satellite, but you can tune it. For normal usage TCP can be even faster than UDP because it adapts itself to the available bandwidth. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122288/57127.